# System of equations - Contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

A problem ask to find the constants $a$, $b$ and $c$ if $f(z)=az^2+bz+c$ and $\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz=2 \pi i$, $\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z+1}dz=4 \pi i$ and $\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-1}dz=8 \pi i$ where the contour is $\gamma = C(0,2)$

So I obtain the system of equations in using the Cauchy theorem  $$1=c$$ $$2=a-b+1$$ $$4=a+b+1$$ $$\implies f(z) = 2z^2+z+1$$ Am I right? Otherwise, 
What do I have to change my answer for it to be true?

Comment: Looks correct, so I'd like to know *exactly* where did you get those equations for the coefficients from. I mean, if I were your teacher.

Comment: @Joanpemo I suppose $\frac{f(z)}{z-k}$ holomorphic for $k=0, 1, -1$. So by the Cauchy theorem, we obtain $2\pi i f(0)=c 2 \pi i = 2 \pi i$, $2\pi i f(-1)=(a-b+1) 2 \pi i = 4 \pi i$ and $2\pi i f(1)=(a+b+1) 2 \pi i = 8 \pi i$. From those equations, we get the system of equations from the question. Is that what you are looking for from me?

Comment: @RobertDavis Exactly that, Thank you.

Comment: @Joanpemo What could we conclude if our $\frac{f(z)}{z-k}$ is not holomorphic? Could we find the constants $a$, $b$ and $c$ or it's impossible?

Comment: @RobertDavis Excuse, **not**  $\;\frac{f(z)}{z-k}\;$ is holomorphic, **only** $\;f(z)\;$ .